# mathBox on jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the code from https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/znah/mathbox/blob/jupyter/examples/notebooks/mathbox.ipynb?flush_cache=true

The notebook raise error `Javascript Error: with_mathbox is not defined`.

I tried by change the
`mathBox: '//cdn.rawgit.com/unconed/mathbox/eaeb8e15/build/mathbox-bundle'`

to be

`mathBox: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathbox@0.1.0/build/mathbox-bundle.min.js'`.

But still not work. I have no background on web or javascript experience so could you pleas suggest?